# How To Reduce HTTPURLConnection Code

Tags: android

**SOLVED:
I have gone ahead and used the recomendation of Retrofit library and it has reduced my code allot. Thank you for the help.**

I have an android application, on the page I have code displayed below when someone clicks on a switch it will use PUT to send the data as a JSON to the server. However im not sure how I can reduce this code in a way that I can use it again. I dont want to have to keep copy and pasting the same code and changing the requestMethod or the type of bytes im writing.

**This is the code in my oncreate, when the switch is turned on it will do what is in Figure B. I want to make it DELETE when the switch is off without having to copy the same code from figure B and changing it and then executing it.:**

```
test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean on = ((Switch) v).isChecked();
            if(on)
            {
                //Do something when switch is on/checked
                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                new newtask().execute();

            }
            else
            {
                //Do something when switch is off/unchecked

            }
        }
    });
```

**Figure B**

```
class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 private Exception exception;


 protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

 URL url = null;
 try {
     String strUrl = "http://192.168.0.104:5053/TEST";
     url = new URL(strUrl);
     HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

     connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
     connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset");
     connection.setDoInput(true);
     connection.setDoOutput(true);

     OutputStream stream = connection.getOutputStream();
     DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(stream);
     connection.connect();
     //Log.d("WARN", "TEST");
     // The LogCat prints out data like:
     // ID:test,Email:test@gmail.com,Pwd:test
    String suuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

     writer.writeBytes("{\"id\" : \""+suuid+ "\", \"sensorType\" : \"sound\", \"threshold\" : \"50\", \"operator\" : \">\", \"actuator\" : \"1\", \"actuatorAction\" : \"4\"}");
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();

     InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
     BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response, "utf-8"));
     String responseLine = bf.readLine();
     while(responseLine != null) {
         sb.append(responseLine);
         responseLine = bf.readLine();
     }

     stream.close();
     System.out.println("executed");
     connection.disconnect();



 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
 return "fff";
 }

 protected String onPostExecute() {
 // TODO: check this.exception
 // TODO: do something with the feed
 return "ASDASD";
 }



 }
```

If any more information is needed on making this clearer please let me know.

Comment: **Suggestion** Use [RetroFit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) .

Comment: I don't have a major issue with each activity maintaining one or more async tasks.  The pre and post steps are usually different, and if you analyze closely you might find that much of the code is different.

Comment: @ADM Thank you, I have gone ahead and used retrofit and reduces the code allot. Im not sure how to make your answer the answer but I thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android-Volley**(deprecated): 
  https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley 
     or

**Retrofit:**

- Type-safe HTTP client
- Retrofit is definitely the better alternative to volley in terms of ease of use, performance,Catching, extensibility, Multipart uploads and other things. It is a type-­safe REST client
  (http://square.github.io/retrofit)

Comment: It will be good if you add some description to the url you provided.

Comment: I have gone ahead and used Retrofit library. The second link provided which explains how to use it and reduces code 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

**Sample Code:**

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("key", "value");
params.put("more", "data");
client.post("https://www.google.com", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        // called before request is started
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
        // called when request is retried
    }
});
```

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very lightweight Ion library for this. Usage examples are on Github: https://github.com/koush/ion

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i would recommend using a networking library (Retrofit, Volly, etc...) since dealing with the http connection directly is a bit more complicated and prone to errors which the libraries have probably addressed already.

But if you still wish to use an http connection directly, You could just make an httpConnection Task that extends async task and gets the necessary params on creation.

for example -

```
public class HttpConnection extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private final String mBytes;
private final String mMethod;

public HttpConnection(String method, String bytes) {
    mMethod = method;
    mBytes = bytes;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    // ... open connection
    writer.writeBytes(mBytes);
    return null;
}
```

Obviously, you can change this up to use whatever params you want/need